# PySerial and readline() return binary string - convert to regular alphanumeric string?

Tags: string, serial-port, pyserial, python-3.3

I'm having an issue with PySerial and Python (3.3): The code I'm running (for now, this is just a simple test case) is as follows:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
result = ser.readline()
parsed = result.split(",")
```

which gives the following error:

```
TypeError: type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

What's my stupid mistake? I think I've traced this to the fact that PySerial's readline is returning a binary string (new in python 3?) and that the string operation "split" is failing when run against a binary string - it works fine if you run this:

```
'1234, asdf, 456, jkl'.split(",")
```

Which gives the expected:

```
['1234', 'asdf', '456', jkl']
```

But then running:

```
b'1234, asdf, 456, jkl'.split(",")
```

gives the error above. Is there a different readline method to use? should I code my own with read (and just read until it sees /r/n) or can I easily convert to a string that will satisfy str.isalnum()? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest solution will be to use a python module called binascii that has a selection of functions for converting the binary string to an ascii string: http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html

EDIT:
The b means that it is a byte array and not a literal string. The correct way to convert the byte array to a litteral string will be to use the str() function:

str(b'1234, asdf, 456, jkl', 'ascii').split(",")

this gives the output you want:
['1234', 'asdf', '456', jkl']

I hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think that does what I'm looking for - the value returned by readline is just a "b-flagged" string: 'code' b'asdf, asdf, asdf' 'code' - which fails str.isalnum() and I really just need to strip the leading "b" - it renders in ASCII, it just has a binary flag? I think I'm missing something. I don't see a binascii method that looks to do this.

Comment: Ok so my answer was wrong but i've edited it to include what is hopefully a working solution!